# Is there a way to execute Sonar's SSLR (squid-based) rules locally (on demand) in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-analysis, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

There is a [SonarQube for IntelliJ](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin), which, even though [a bit](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin/issues?state=open) [temperamental](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin/issues/34), allows you to download rule violations from Sonar and view them directly in IntelliJ (the downside being the analysis runs on the server, necessitating a sync; the upside being you get exactly what you'd get in Sonar), and there is the QAPlugin, which allows you to [import](http://qaplug.com/about/tutorials/#QAPlug-Sonar) Sonar's Checkstyle, PMD and Findbugs rules and run them locally, but it does not support [SSLR/squid rules](http://qaplug.uservoice.com/forums/64605-general/suggestions/5234334-feature-request-support-for-the-sonar-sslr-engine#comments) yet. Sonar, however, seems to be [moving away from PMD & Co. towards SSLR](http://www.sonarqube.org/already-158-checkstyle-and-pmd-rules-deprecated-by-sonarqube-java-rules/).

**Is there currently a way to import Sonar's SSLR-based rules in IntelliJ and to run them locally?**

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [official SonarQube IntelliJ plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+IntelliJ) which allows you to run SonarQube analysis within IntelliJ - whatever the rules you've configured on your SonarQube instance (SonarQube rules, Checkstyle, PMD, Findbugs).

Comment: By the looks of it, it's just an old version of the community plugin I linked to above, isn't it?

Comment: Also, the version in the IntelliJ repo is v0.1, whereas the docs say it should be v1.0?

Comment: Found it here: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4971?pr=idea 
But got error message "Plugin SonarQube is incompatible with current installation". :(

Comment: Which version of SQ are you using?

Comment: /api/server/version returns 4.0

Comment: IntelliJ is v13.1.1 and the IntelliJ SonarQube plugin I tried to install from disk is version 1.0

Comment: As you can see on the Wiki, you need SQ 4.1 at least: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+IntelliJ

Comment: Argh. OK. Thanks. Though that should't stop me from actually installing the plugin in the first place, should it? It should just not work (correctly)...

Answer (score 0):

Up from version 2 the SonarQube Community Plugin allows you not only to download issues from Sonar and view them directly in IntelliJ, but also to run any local analysis script, the results are then shown in Intellij like any other inspection.

You don't need to import any rules, instead you just run a local analysis script using the sonar-runner or any build tool plugin like mvn sonar plugin:

```
/path/to/mvn sonar:sonar -DskipTests=true -Dsonar.language=java  -Dsonar.analysis.mode=incremental -Dsonar.host.url=http://your.sonar.host -Dsonar.profile=your_squid_based_profile
```

this will create a sonar-report.json file:

```
Export results to /path/to/your/project/target/sonar/sonar-report.json
```

You can configure the plugin which script to execute and where to read the results. Also the plugin does not care if the issues comes from squid or any other rule set.

See also: https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin